# How to fade in/out ui image smooth automatic or/and with keys?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in the editor if i'm changing the image color alpha from 0 to 1 it will make the whole screen dark black.

but when i'm using this code attached it to the image it self it's not doing anything it's not changing the alpha of the image at all.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Fader : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Attach an Image you want to fade in the GameObject's Inspector
    public Image m_Image;
    //Use this to tell if the toggle returns true or false
    bool m_Fading;

    void Update()
    {
        //If the toggle returns true, fade in the Image
        if (m_Fading == true)
        {
            //Fully fade in Image (1) with the duration of 2
            m_Image.CrossFadeAlpha(1, 2.0f, false);
        }
        //If the toggle is false, fade out to nothing (0) the Image with a duration of 2
        if (m_Fading == false)
        {
            m_Image.CrossFadeAlpha(0, 2.0f, false);
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        //Fetch the Toggle's state
        m_Fading = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 30), m_Fading, "Fade In/Out");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you  seeing the the Toggle it creates in OnGui?

Comment: @ephb i see it and i see now that the alpha color of the image must be on value 255 all the time only then it will work the fade in/out if the al[ha color is on 0 it will not work.  it's fading in/out only when the alpha color is on value 255 all the time.  second i see that when it's fading out it's fast 2 seconds but when it's fading in it's very slow.  much more then 2 seconds.

Comment: The bool parameter changes if it ignores timescale or not.
In general I would advise you to look into [DOTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/) instead. It has a free version and is much more flexible.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the source of the code. When I looked up the parameters I noticed this is straight out of the Unity documentation.